# Bundle knockout.js in ASP.NET Web Application - VS2013

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

I'm trying to add a bundle for Knockout in my application. From NuGet, I got two scripts:
*knockout-3.0.0.debug.js* and 
*knockout-3.0.0.js*

I'm using the following code.

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/knockout").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/knockout-{version}.js"));
```

For some reason, it will include the "debug" version:

```
<script src="/Scripts/knockout-3.0.0.debug.js"></script>
```

My question:
How can I get the non-debug version?
(I have tried running in both debug and release configurations, with the same result)

Best regards,
Thomas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless `EnableOptimizations` is `true` or the debug attribute in the compilation Element  in the `Web.config` file is set to false, files will not be bundled or minified. Additionally, the `.min` version of files will not be used,  the full debug versions will be selected. `EnableOptimizations`  overrides the debug attribute in the compilation Element  in the `Web.config` file

[more info](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification)